# Nested for loop not running properly as well as function not adding array values

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

The outer for loop is only running once instead of 3 times, and then when calling the function sum the array values are not added together.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int sum(int a[][3]);

int main()
{

        int array[2][3];

        for (int num1; num1 < 3; num1 ++)
        {
                for (int num2; num2 < 4; num2 ++)
                {
                        cout << "Enter a number to be stored in array[" << num1 << "][" << num2 << "]: ";
                        cin >> array[num1][num2];
                }
        }

        sum(array);


        return 0;
}


// Below this is all of the functions that are used in this program

int sum(int a[][3])
{
        int sum;

        for (int num1; num1 < 3; num1 ++)
        {
                for (int num2; num2 < 4; num2 ++)
                        sum += a[num1][num2];
        }

        cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;

}
```

I've tried switching the values of the function's arguments, such as making it "a[][]" and "a[2][3]" but neither of these worked, as for the for loop I tried making the value of num1 go up to 12 thinking it must be adding one every iteration but that of course didn't work

Comment: Note that `num1` and `num2` are never initialized, and that `a[2]` when `a` has a length of 2 is a out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Try initializing your variables. They do not default to anything. And the bounds on your loops are wrong. Review the introduction of arrays in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: `int sum;` doesn't initialize the variable, its value is undetermined.

Comment: Also, judging by the prototype `int sum(int a[][3]);`, that function is supposed to return the sum, not print it.

Comment: thank you everyone for the help, after initializing num1 and num2 with =0 and changing the function to return sum instead of print it it's working. Was frustrated with that but like usual the answer is very simple

Answer (score 1):

```
    int array[2][3];

    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < 2; num1 ++)
    {
            for (int num2 = 0; num2 < 3; num2 ++)
```

Try that and you might have more success.

1. `int num1 = 0;` instead of `int num1;` gives the variable `num1` an initial value of `0`. The idea that you don't have to bother giving a variable an initial value is a strange one. Not sure where beginners pick that one up. You have the same problem with `int sum;` which should be `int sum = 0;`.
2. Arrays have indexes that go from 0 to (but not including) the size of the array. So if your array has a size of 2, the correct loop for that is `for (int num1 = 0; num1 < 2; num1++)` not `for (int num1 = 0; num1 < 3; num1++)`. It's simple to remember, use `<` in the for loop and use the same number for the limit as the size of the array.
3. Finally, most likely your function is supposed to **return** the sum, not **print** it (beginners often get those two terms confused). The printing is done in `main`. That would look like this

   ```
    int main()
    {
        ...
        // call the function sum and print the returned value
        cout << "The sum is: " << sum(array) << endl;
    }

    int sum(int a[][3])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        ...
        // return the sum
        return sum;
    }
   ```

Comment: thank you for the help, you made it very easy to understand